# how to install a .dmg controller in ubuntu?

Tags: scanner

I've heard that it is possible to use Mac installers on Ubuntu. Is that true? if it is, I've got the controller as a .dmg file. How can i install this controller on ubuntu?

Some context: 
I have a Fuji Xerox multifunctional printer that doesn't have controllers for Linux. I've managed to get the printer working, but haven't been able to get the scanner working. I've tried everything but no luck :(

I would really appreciate if somebody could help me, Thanks in advance.
(Please avoid obvious answers as "Just use Simple Scan and it'll recognize it", i've tried that)

Comment: neither you can install mac .dmg file nor you can convert them for linux..

Answer (score 0):

If you have a mac handy, then you can do this on the mac:

```
hdiutil convert /path/to/filename.dmg -format UDTO -o /path/to/savefile.iso
```

Other than that, there is no way to convert or open the dmg file.